# union operator exercise

Tags: sql, oracle11g

My exercise states to write a query that contains a `UNION` of two `SELECT`s that contain the columns `REGION_ID, REGION_NAME, COUNTRY_NAME` and  "No of Locations".  The result must be a list of ALL countries with the number of locations in the country. The list must be ordered by Region ID and country name.

I don't quite understand the logic with the operator `union`, and the result of this query must have the list of all countries with the number of locations in the country. What I've done is:

```
(select reg.region_id, reg.region_name, coun.country_name
from countries coun, regions reg
where reg.region_id=coun.region_id
order by region_id, country_name)
UNION
(select ...);
```

I'm not sure what's next here. I'm not sure if the parameters I've written are correct. I'd like to know how to use the `union` operator here.
By the way, I'm using the hr table schema.

Comment: You can achieve what is requested without a union query.  Something doesn't make sense.

Comment: the thing is my professor wants it in a union query. which one doesn't make sense the question or my query? most likely my query doesn't make sense

Comment: The question does not make sense.

Comment: Presumably you're deleting the details on all of your questions when they're answered so that the professor can't Google for where you found them?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think what you professor wants is to be country names and region names to be listed within the same column. In this case it makes a good sense to use UNION. The resulting query will be something like:

```
(select region_id, 0, region_name
from regions)
UNION
(select reg.region_id, coun.contry_id, coun.country_name
from countries coun, regions reg
where reg.region_id=coun.region_id)
order by 1, 2
```

In the query above I have assumed that you have a column called country_id (it is good for sorting, so that first comes the region #1 followed bay all countries belonging to this region, that comes region #2 with its countries, etc.) If you do not have the country_id, you can achieve the same sorting by using this query:

```
(select region_id, 0, region_name
from regions)
UNION
(select reg.region_id, 1, coun.country_name
from countries coun, regions reg
where reg.region_id=coun.region_id)
order by 1, 2, 3
```

Comment: the first one doesn't work but the second one does thanks. I'm new in sql and i haven't familiarize myself yet with the function of union could you explain the what "0" does in the select section and the numbers "1,2,3" in the order by part. i don't understand their function in the query.

Comment: it is all done for sorting. when you `UNION` two or more select statements the column names may be different in each statement. Therefore, you will not be able to `ORDER BY` column names. Thus, you are ordering by the column index (index #1, #2, #3). Thus, the syntax is `ORDER BY 1, 2, 3`. Notice how I made the column #2 for the region `0`, and for the countries `1`. In this case the region will always be first, followed by its countries. BTW, if you like the answer, please accept it and upvote

Comment: oh okay thanks, how about the the column "No. of Locations?" because my professor wants to output a column that has the number of locations

Comment: not sure what it is. You have provided just two tables: region and country. I guess locations is something with a country?